# text justify in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, presentations

I like to justify the texts inside the block using beamer.
I cant do that in presentation[image]. Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `\justifying` from the [ragged2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package; you can patch the `\frame` command to use `\justyfing`, but you will also have to invoke `\justifying` for some other environments which internally use `\raggedleft` (for example, the beamer blocks, and the list-like environments `enumerate`, `itemize`, etc.). A little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{text}
\justifying
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I didnt invoke \justifying every time.....Also Can you please tell me- How can I write the block title at the center?

Comment: This fails when you use `\begin{frame}{frametitle}...\end{frame}`... the frame title is put in the frame body, not header.

Comment: If I try using `\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}` when I have some text next to an image like [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291138/beamer-columns-environment-and-text-next-to-image/291140#291140), the text is not being justified. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Marco add ad-hoc `\justifying` on the column block, or patch the column block as was done for text.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Thanks for the answer. But what is the difference between \justify and \justifying? I have googled the question but did not find any answer. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe also helpful: `\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}` to automatically add the command to each block in beamer.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `\parbox{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{text}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It is a bit less exotic than the other answer's solution.

Comment: you could also add minipage

Answer (score 11):

I [found](http://latex-beamer-class.10966.n7.nabble.com/justified-text-in-beamer-td1491.html) that one can achieve text justification in beamer by including

`\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm}`

in the preamble.

I have done so in a big document with 70 slides without noticing any side effect. Nevertheless, the link is very old (2008) so I do not know if care should be exercised in the application of this workaround (possible compatibility issues, conflicts with packages, environments and the like, etc.).

Comment: but than you lost function of this command where you needed. i would not do this.

Comment: works like charm!