# How to justify some block of text in beamer?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I'm doing a presentation in `beamer` and would like to justify some text as one does in *LibreOffice Writer* or *Word*, cause I don't like how it looks aligned to the left. Is there a command that does the trick?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55589/text-justify-in-beamer help?

Comment: You do know that justification is turned off in `beamer` for a reason, I assume.