# Beamer: Text Justification in blocks globally

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I can get text justification in blocks by using `\justifying`. Is it possible to justify the text within each block globally without using `\justifying` in each block? Thanks

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}


% For global Justification
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\justifying
\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm} 


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{block}{Test}
The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\end{block}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you could load the `ragged2e` package and add a `\justifying` at the end of the `block begin` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %new code
\usetheme{default}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}  %new code

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{block}{Test}
            The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MYaseen208 you're welcome :)

Comment: @MYaseen208 thanks for the bounty!

Comment: You are welcome. You and your solution have made my life easier. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible to do global justification in table cells? I can do by using by using \justifying in each cell but it is not very elegant. Any idea!

Comment: For information I'm using LyX.

Comment: you can create a new column type and call `justifying` inside it, for example: `\newcolumntype{J}{>{\justifying\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}` Then you'll have something like `\begin{tabular}{J} this text will be justified  \end{tabular}`. This works in LaTeX, I never used LyX so I really don't know if you need something different there

Comment: Is it possible justifying the content outside of blocks, in all frames?

Comment: @paulequilibrio see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55589/text-justify-in-beamer

Answer (score 0):

In my case the code given by domenico camasta didn't work. But the following modification works

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}{}
```

For justifying texts out side the blocks, I used the following command along with the above codes:

```
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't add anything that isn't already covered by the existing answer. I can't see how it wouldn't work in the first place.