# Beamer: Global text justification in the `example` enviroment

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

Using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148696/22364) answer, I can justify text in `block` environments globally. However, if I replace the `block` environment by an `example` environment, the above solution doesn't work:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %new code
\usetheme{default}

\addtobeamertemplate{example begin}{}{\justifying}  %new code

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{example}
    The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over
    the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown
    fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy
    dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped
    over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The
    brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the
    lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I justify text in the `example` environment globally?

Version: Beamer 3.55 from TeX Live 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template you want to modify is called `block example begin` and not `example begin`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %new code
\usetheme{default}

\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{}{\justifying}  %new code

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{example}
    The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over
    the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown
    fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy
    dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped
    over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The
    brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the
    lazy dog. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]