# Beamer like ClassicThesis

Tags: beamer, typography, classicthesis

If I write my thesis with `ClassicThesis`, how can I fix `beamer` layout to get a similar setup?

Does exist a template for this problem?

Comment: Can you please show you're settings using `classicthesis`? Which settings would you like to transfer to `beamer`?

Comment: It is of common use to prefer sans serif font over serif font for slides (`beamer`) mainly for readability reasons. I totally agree that default style with `beamer` is awful and for example I pretty much enjoy Flip beamer's theme. If matching `classicthesis` is the main concern, you can create your own `beamer` template. I'll be difficult to directly help you if you don't provide at least an idea of how a slide would look like.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I don't yet write my thesis. For this question I'm thinking about something similar to `ClassicThesis` Manual. My question is general (maybe too much general), I would like a `beamer`typographic style consistent with that of the thesis

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. Please try to narrow down those aspects from `classicthesis` that you would like to see in your `beamer` presentation.

Comment: @s__C: Tanks for your reply, I like default style too but for my future thesis I prefer a more homogeneous style.

Comment: Aspects I mean are: font, colors, table layout, math-font, chapter title, environment for code (Matlab or Octave), external link, list (itemize or enumerate), ToC. Mainly these are what I would.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by making a beamer presentation in ClassicThesis style. They are different things; you want to grow "radicchio rosso di Treviso” in the style of Bruxelles artichokes: both good vegetables to eat, but you can't compare the way they are grown up.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for your very funny comment.

Answer (score 4):

As the comments note, what makes a presentation good is not what makes a thesis good. However, some serif fonts work well in presentations if no one will be seated far from the screen. And especially if the subject matter is literary, it may not be inappropriate for the style of a presentation to echo that of the thesis. Try something like this, which borrows a trick from [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55590):

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex:
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox,fontspec,microtype,ragged2e}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts,serif,structuresmallcapsserif}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={Kerning=Uppercase}]{Minion Pro}
\linespread{1.0344}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\beamertemplatesolidbackgroundcolor{Snow}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
\definecolor{alert}{HTML}{347941}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=alert}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{informative title}
  \framesubtitle{optional subtitle}

  The studio was filled with the rich odor of roses, and when the
  light summer wind stirred amidst the trees of the garden there came
  through the open door the heavy scent of the lilac, or the more
  delicate perfume of the pink-flowering thorn.

  \begin{itemize}
    \justifying
  \item An item.
  \item An \alert{alerted} item.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the sample code]

Sorry, I can’t help with math, Matlab, or Octave, since my own documents never involve them, but perhaps this is enough to get you started.