# Beamer, columns environment and text next to image

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment

I am not able to get the text next to the image. As you can see, it is shifted downward.
p.s. columns width can be changed.

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{2cm}}{\vspace*{1mm}}
\geometry{paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=100pt,text margin right=100pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{Title}}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-1x1}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{11cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item \lipsum[3]
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference point of an image is at its bottom.

Add some space in the left column, `\vspace{\topsep}` is the same as what's added by the `itemize` environment in the right column. In other cases you can use `\vspace{0pt}`.

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\geometry{paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=100pt,text margin right=100pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{Title}}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{\topsep}

\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-1x1}%
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With `\begin{columns}[T]` you can have the columns aligned to the top.

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{2cm}}{\vspace*{1mm}}
\geometry{paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=100pt,text margin right=100pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{Title}}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-1x1}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{11cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item \lipsum[3]
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried `t` but it it had not worked. Hence it was `T` and not `t`. Thank you.

Comment: I am a little bit puzzled because `T`, as you said, works; `t` does not, while the [manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) at page 25 says "Trying this, he is not quite satisfied with the result as the block on the left has a different height than the one on the right. He thinks it would be nicer if they were vertically top-aligned. So he adds the [t] option to the columns environment."

Comment: @Marco From page 125: T is similar to the t option, but T aligns the tops of the first lines while t aligns the so-called baselines of the first lines. If strange things seem to happen in conjunction with the t option (for example if a graphic suddenly “drops down” with the t option instead of “going up,”), try using this option instead.