# How to use `paracol` in `beamer` environment?

Tags: beamer, paracol

instead of using default `beamer` command `columns` I want to use `paracol` environment - to top-align columns.

But,

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 \begin{paracol}{2}
```

Is it fixable?

```
  \begin{frame}[fragile]{}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
      xxx
      \switchcolumn
      yyy
    \end{paracol}
  \end{frame}
```

Comment: Paracol doesn't like being inside minipages either.  IIRC, the column widths are computed in the preamble, not on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to top align the contents of two columns in a `beamer` frame, then there is no need for `paracols`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{columns}[t]
      \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          xxx
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          yyy

          more text
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply - it is what I am looking for. But, `frame` `t` is unnecessary for me, and, there is last problem - how - make column text justified, like in `paracol`?

Comment: Regarding justifying text: [text justify in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55589/134144)  might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. But, why `paracol` is not supported? Floats are usually easily insertable into the slides.

Comment: @LexUshakov: `beamer`disables the floating behavious of floats. This is why you can use `table` and `figure` "as usual" but their contents are placed where they are used in the code.